# numpy 3D array reshape/flattern to 1D array based on row order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, reshape

I have a 3D NumPy array

```
x = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1],
               [2, 2, 2, 2]],

              [[0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1],
               [2, 2, 2, 2]]])
```

If I want to flatten the 3D array to 1D array by taking row n°0 of `x[0]`, row n°0 of `x[1]`, row n°1 of `x[0]`, row n°1 of `x[1]`, row n°2 of `x[0]`, row n°2 of `x[1]`, and get the following layout:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

How can I achieve this? Tried to reshape, flatten, none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack then flatten the array:

```
>>> np.stack(x, axis=1).flatten()
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.